# Quotation marks

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I get php to output this correctly (with working html-iframe)? It doesn't work because the single quotation mark is already used but the double quotation mark is used too.

```
echo "<p data-toggle='popover' title='word' data-html='true' data-content='<iframe src='https://www.somelink.com'></iframe>'>";
```

(echo is php, data-toggle etc are bootstrap, data-content defines what is inside a popover)

Comment: you can try with echo '<p data-toggle="popover" title="word" data-html="true" data-content="<iframe src=\'https://www.somelink.com\'></iframe>">';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try stripslashing your string.

```
echo "<p data-toggle='popover' title='word' data-html='true' data-content='<iframe src=\"https://www.somelink.com\"></iframe>'>";
```

More information about stripslashes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 2):

Consider [escaping the double quotes characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) that enclose your `src` attribute using backslashes `\"`:

```
echo "<p data-toggle='popover' title='word' data-html='true' data-content='<iframe src=\"https://www.somelink.com\"></iframe>'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the data content for JS purposes I would store only the URL and not a full Iframe tag. This way you can use single quotes and keep everything with proper double qoutes:

```
echo '<p data-toggle="popover" title="word" data-html="true" data-content="https://www.somelink.com">';
```

then in your js just create an iframe assign the url to its source and append.

It seems like bad practice to have full markup in a data attribute and this allows you to keep cleaner code quote wise.